# How to replace Fragment with a view inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm writing a DialogFragment that display a PreferenceFragment inside it, but it does not work

**SettingDialogFragment.java**

```
package uet.dtui.megaereader;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class SettingDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_book_setting, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        View root = getView();
        FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.content_fm_frame);
        System.out.println(frame);

        /* My stub ...*/
        SettingsFragment setting = new SettingsFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putBoolean(SettingsFragment.BOOK_SETTING_ONLY, true);
        setting.setArguments(bundle);
        /*             */

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_fm_frame, setting)
            .commit();
    }

}
```

**layout_book_setting.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_fm_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I get the error:

> No view found for id 0x7f0e0093
>   (uet.dtui.megaereader:id/content_fm_frame) for fragment
>   SettingsFragment{53664f7c #2 id=0x7f0e0093}

But the `System.out` statement before replace still work:

> android.widget.FrameLayout{53539680 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0
>
> ## 7f0e0093 app:id/content_fm_frame}

So, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid nested fragments. Because you can get illegal state exception on your fragment detect. you can get this exception offen on Samsung
devices which use kitkat. This is known  bug in android about nested fragment

> getActivity().getChildFragmentManager().replace(R.id.content_fm_frame,
>   fragment_instance).commit();

Comment: @user2447581 check my new answer.